# Cakephp Custom Datasource Save/Update

Tags: php, api, rest, cakephp, datasource

Using the latest CakePHP build 1.3.6.

I'm writing a custom datasource for a external REST API.  I've got all the read functionality working beautifully.  I'm struggling with the Model::save & Model::create.

According to the documentation, the below methods must be implemented (see below and notice it does not mention calculate). These are all implemented.  However, I was getting an "Fatal error: Call to undefined method ApiSource::calculate()".  So I implemented the ApiSource::calculate() method.

> describe($model) listSources() At
>   least one of: 
>   create($model, $fields = array(), $values = array())
>   read($model, $queryData = array())
>   update($model, $fields = array(), $values = array()) 
>   delete($model, $id
>   = null)

```
public function calculate(&$model, $func, $params = array())
 {
  pr($model->data); // POST data
  pr($func); // count
  pr($params); // empty
  return '__'.$func; // returning __count;
 }
```

If make a call from my model

```
$this->save($this->data)
```

It is calling calculate, but none of the other implemented methods.  I would expect it to either call ApiSource::create() or ApiSource::update()

Any thoughts or suggustions?

Comment: Hmm, I'm using custom data sources and they don't have a `calculate` method. Could you do a `debug_backtrace` to see where exactly that gets called from?

Comment: What version of cake are you using? From what I read, this started in 1.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Leo, you tipped me in the right direction. The answer was in the model that was using the custom datasource.  That model MUST define your _schema.

```
class User extends AppModel
{  
    public $name = 'User';

    public $useDbConfig = 'cvs';

    public $useTable = false;

    public $_schema = array(
        'firstName' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'length' => 30
        ),
        'lastName' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'length' => 30
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'length' => 50
        ),
        'password' =>  array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'length' => 20
        )
        );

...
}
```

I'm guessing that if you implement a describe() method in the custom datasource that will solve the problem too. In this case it needed to be predefined to authorize the saves and/or creation.

Comment: so what are you saying zmonteca ? by defining a schema cake does not call the Datasource:calculate() method? I am in the middle of creating a datasource and I want to be able to paginate the data without having to create custom paginate methods in the model. However, cake complains about there being no calculate() method in my datasource. Please provide more detail to your solution.

Comment: Actually, I got by this by defining an exists() and  _findCount() functions, which seemed more inline with what I was actually doing (using an API to expose data).  Also - when your datasource is done, if you can, make it publicly available on github.

Comment: calculate needs to be defined. For me, it was a bit of a hack. I defined the following: public function calculate(&$model, $func, $params = array())
 {
  $this->object = false;
  return self::COUNT;
 }  Then in my function read() { } I made an exception for when $this->object = false.

Answer (score 0):

From the API: http://api13.cakephp.org/class/dbo-source#method-DboSourcecalculate

"Returns an SQL calculation, i.e. COUNT() or MAX()"

A quick search in ~/cake finds 20 matches in 8 files. One of those is the definition in dbo_source.php

The other seven are:

- dbo_source.test.php
- code_coverage_manager.test.php
- code_coverage_manager.php
- dbo_db2.php
- model.php
- tree.php
- containable.php

Without delving too deeply into this, I suspect your problem lies in Model::save

You'll probably have to define a calculate method to suit the structure of your custom datasource because Cake won't know how to do that.